# Symfony (3.2.6) SQL Error | ([Semantical Error] line 0, col 39 near 'parking_ticket_settings': Error: Class 'parking_ticket_settings' is not defined.)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.2

I have problem with SQL query in Symfony (3.2.6).

I am trying to run this code:

```
$em->persist($AxfonePushPayment);
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT parking_ticket_settings.id FROM parking_ticket_settings JOIN zone z ON(z.id = parking_ticket_settings.zone_id) WHERE z.zone_identifier = '" . $AxfonePushPayment->getZone() . "'");

$ptsID = $query->getResult();
```

But this error appears:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 39 near 'parking_ticket_settings': Error: Class 'parking_ticket_settings' is not defined." at /var/www/app.clickpark.cz/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php line 63 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException(code: 0): [Semantical Error] line 0, col 39 near 'parking_ticket_settings': Error: Class 'parking_ticket_settings' is not defined. at /var/www/app.clickpark.cz/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:63, Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException(code: 0): SELECT parking_ticket_settings.id FROM parking_ticket_settings JOIN zone z ON(z.id = parking_ticket_settings.zone_id) WHERE z.zone_identifier = 'BERF' at /var/www/app.clickpark.cz/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:41)"}
```

When i exec query in mysql it works properly.

Does anybody know where is the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide Entity class name not table name, e.g.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM AppBundle:ParkingTicketSettings p')
$ptsID = $query->getResult();
```